# unknown the error cause related to ttf in py

Tags: python, compiler-errors

when I write a py toy

```
import wordcloud

# 构建词云对象w，设置词云图片宽、高、字体、背景颜色等参数
w = wordcloud.WordCloud(width=1000,
                        height=700,
                        background_color='white',
                        font_path='arial.ttf')

w.generate('jfsdkkljdfhdasjl hdlafjfdj')

w.to_file('output2-poem.png')
```

I meet the error
OSError: cannot open resource

Answer (score 0):

Check if the filename or path for your .ttf file is correct. If you're on Linux, you can set `font_path` to `None` to use the default DroidSansMono font.